# Set Background Tint To EditText Views Programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I'd like to have a slight tint of grey in the background of a `EditText` view, almost like the text's constantly highlighted, and I need to add this programmatically. I've tried `setBackground()`, `setBackgroundTintList()`, `setBackgroundTintMode()`, but no one of them seems to work.

Here is the code...

```
    EditText label = new EditText(this);
    label.setTextSize(4*dp);
    label.setTypeface(null,Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams labelParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    labelParams.setMargins(80,0,0,0);
    labelParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    labelParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    label.setLayoutParams(labelParams);
    rootView.addView(label);
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Lets try this:

```
editText.getBackground().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.your_color), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

Answer (score 0):

a text highlight won't appear unless the user long-press to select-all!

so this is a twofer:

`setHighlightColor(Color.RED)` will give the highlight color you want, ONLY when you select-all

so you have to `setSelection(0, length)` as you type

use `TextWatcher` to auto-select it for you as you type:

```
    et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            et.setSelection(0, s.length());
        }
    });
```

but BE CAREFUL, because the text is "selected", one "delete" will wipe it out and also typed-text can accidentally be replaced

You will have to delicately override some of this default behavior in your TextWatcher. Please play with it, you'll discover some interesting behavior!